# typecast Object[] into OtherObject[]

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class ABC {
    public int i;
    public float f;

    public ABC(int d1,float d2) {
        i=d1;
        f=d2;
    }
}
```

I have created a ArrayList of ABC object .

```
    ArrayList<ABC> list = new ArrayList<ABC>();
    ABC abc1=new ABC(1,1.0f);
    ABC abc2=new ABC(2,2.0f);
    list.add(abc1);
    list.add(abc2);
```

Now I want to convert the ArrayList into array with `toArray()` method, but this Method returns `Object[];`.

Now I can typecast elements of `Object[]` one by one into ABC type object and create `ABC[];`,

**but Is there any other way to typecast the Object[] into ABC[] in one command ?  Something like this**

```
    ABC[] array=(ABC[])list.toArray();
```

though this command throws this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; can not be cast to [LABC;**

Any Help

Comment: Cast does not change the class of an object, and the class of the array is `Object[]`.  You can use System.arraycopy to copy the array into one of the desired class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) has a `toArray` method that returns the generically-typed array, so you can [`use`ArrayList`'s implementation of that`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/):

```
ABC[] array = new ABC [list.size()]
array = list.toArray(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

[toArray() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))

```
ABC[] array = list.toArray(new ABC[list.size()])
```